# The germ diffeomorphism set is a group

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, singularity-theory

**Definition.** *Let germ $\phi\colon (\mathbb{R}^n,0)\to  (\mathbb{R}^n,0)$, is germ of diffeomorphism, if there exist $\psi\colon  (\mathbb{R}^n,0)\to (\mathbb{R}^{n},0)$, such that $\psi\circ \phi = \phi \circ \psi = 1_{\mathbb{R}^n,0}$.*

I need prove that, the set $\operatorname{Dif}( \mathbb{R}^n,0)$ is a group under the composition.

I'm confused with the definition of it being a germ of diffeomorphism, I am trying to test the lock, but I have not been able to.

*Let $f,g\in Dif(\mathbb{R}^n,0)$ then there exist $\varphi\colon(\mathbb{R}^n,0)\to(\mathbb{R}^n,0)$ such that $f\circ \varphi=\varphi\circ f=1_{\mathbb{R}^n,0}$*. Again there exist $\psi\colon (\mathbb{R}^n,0)\to (\mathbb{R}^n,0)$ such that $g\circ \psi=\varphi\circ g=1_{\mathbb{R}^n,0}$ . Now I've to show that $f\circ g\in Dif(\mathbb{R}^n,0)$, I have not been able to show that the closure is hold.

any suggestion or help is welcome

Comment: What about $\psi \circ \varphi$?

Comment: @Rushy I am not sure but $(f\circ \varphi)\circ(g\circ \psi)=(f\circ \varphi\circ \psi\circ g)$, and I have to get to the form $(f\circ g)\circ (\varphi\circ \psi)$

Comment: You want to find a $\phi : (\mathbb R^n, 0) \to (\mathbb R^n, 0)$ such that $(f \circ g) \circ \phi = \phi \circ (f \circ g) = 1_{(\mathbb R^n, 0)}$. Try this for $\phi = \psi \circ \varphi$.

Comment: @Rushy I That: $\phi\circ(f\circ g)=(\phi\circ f)\circ g=[(\psi\circ\varphi)\circ f]\circ g=[\psi\circ (\varphi\circ f)]\circ g=(\psi\circ 1_{(\mathbb{R}^n,0)})\circ g=\psi\circ g=1_{(\mathbb{R}^n,0)})$, using a similar argument I show that $(f\circ g)\circ \phi=1_{(\mathbb{R}^n,0)})$, so $f\circ g\in Dif(\mathbb{R}^n,0)$, it's correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The other thing you have to show it is closed under inverses, and the technique is similar

Comment: @Rushy, Regarding the construction of the inverse I have a doubt, the inverse of $f\in Diff(\mathbb{R}^n,0)$ if there is $g\in Dif(\mathbb{R}^n,0)$ such that $f\circ g=g\circ f=1_{(\mathbb{R}^n,0)}$ where $1_{(\mathbb{R}^n,0)}$ is the element of identity in $Dif(\mathbb{R}^n,0)$, 
However, by definition, whenever I make the composition, I obtain the identity

Comment: That's correct. There isn't a whole lot to show since the inverse is precisely the $\varphi$ that you require in the definition of $f$ to be a germ of diffeomorphism. Hence closure under inverses is pretty much by definition.